# GStreamer and music processing

Tags: c++, audio, gstreamer

I want to use gstreamer library to work with sound in my c++ application. Can you tell me there are any ways to change sound tempo, pitch, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Investigate [Songbird](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Getting_Started_with_Songbird/04_Usage_of_Songbird/4.5_Equalizer) I believe they may have developed an equalizer module for GStreamer.

Answer (score 3):

With [pitch](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-soundtouch.html) plugin you can change sound pitch:

```
$ gst-launch filesrc location=sound.mp3
    ! decodebin ! audioconvert
    ! pitch pitch=3
    ! autoaudiosink
```

Or tempo:

```
$ gst-launch filesrc location=sound.mp3
    ! decodebin ! audioconvert
    ! pitch tempo=2
    ! autoaudiosink
```

Or rate.

Also there is huge LADSPA-library wrapper [ladspa](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-ladspa.html).
I had some bad expirience with it, but maybe it is more stable now.
It has several plugins to control pitch, tempo and much more.

This also may be of interest if you are planning to work with sound:

- nice plugin library [audiofx](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-audiofx.html) with various filters, e.g. there is compressor/expander plugin [audiodynamic](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-audiodynamic.html).
- [equalizer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-equalizer.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from max taldykin's suggestion, which returned an error in my version of GStreamer (0.10.35), I found a pipeline that does work. For example, to shift the song 1 step up maintaining the tempo, you should pitch 6%:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=02-have_you_ever.mp3 ! \
    decodebin ! audioconvert ! pitch pitch=1.06 tempo=1.0 ! \
    audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

does the job for me.